# Documentation for FxCop analysis in VSTS?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, fxcop

I have a VSTS build of a simple .net application and I am looking to incorporate some static code analysis in the pipeline.

Is there any documentation for using FxCop? I can see plenty of mentions of using it with Visual Studio, but nothing of how to integrate it within VSTS.

Thanks in advance, Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Code Analysis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TotalALM.totalalm-codeanalysis) Task for VSTS (from the Marketplace) and use this task on your pipeline.

The documentation for the extension exists in the link above and also in [GitHub](https://github.com/TotalALM/VSTS-Tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Code%20Analysis).

[image]